# Updating a custom p:datatable from a commandButton in another datatable one solution works and other does not

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to update a datatable from a command button in another datatable.
I am using primefaces custom components.
I had this code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="eid_pnlGrp" layout="block" class="row_div">

    <cust:panel id="ediDetailsTbl" export="true"
        refreshAction="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.searchEidStatus(subscriberContainer.accountNumber,2)}"
        table="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.eidInquiryTbl}" autoPublish="true"
        layout="table">

        <f:facet name="preActions">
            <p:column id="actionCol" exportable="false"
                headerText="Sub EID">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="commandStyle">
                <p:commandButton id="actionBtn" value=" " async="true"
                    onstart="PF('eid_Blk').show();"
                    oncomplete="PF('eid_Blk').hide();"
    actionListener="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.loadEidFlatDetails(cimTableUtils.getCellValue(record, 'GetEidDetails.SUB_EID')!=null?cimTableUtils.getCellValue(record, 'GetEidDetails.SUB_EID'):cimTableUtils.getCellValue(record, 'GetEidDetailsByAccountNo.SUB_EID'))}"
                    update=":#{p:component('eid_pnlGrp')}"
                    process=":#{p:component('eid_pnlGrp')}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
        </f:facet>
    </cust:panel>

    <cust:panel export="true" id="eid_flat_details"
        rendered="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.eidFlatDetailsTbl ne null }"
        table="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.eidFlatDetailsTbl}"
        autoPublish="false" layout="table">
    </cust:panel>

</h:panelGroup>
```

Now when the table was rendered. The pagination was not working.
When I made a slight change and enclosed the second cust:panel inside a panel group and updated that from the command button, it worked fine.
The changed code is:

```
<h:panelGroup id="eid_pnlGrp" layout="block" class="row_div">

    <cust:panel id="ediDetailsTbl" export="true"
        refreshAction="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.searchEidStatus(subscriberContainer.accountNumber,2)}"
        table="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.eidInquiryTbl}" autoPublish="true"
        layout="table">

        <f:facet name="preActions">
            <p:column id="actionCol" exportable="false"
                headerText="Sub EID">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="commandStyle">
                <p:commandButton id="actionBtn" value=" " async="true"
                    onstart="PF('eid_Blk').show();"
                    oncomplete="PF('eid_Blk').hide();"
    actionListener="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.loadEidFlatDetails(cimTableUtils.getCellValue(record, 'GetEidDetails.SUB_EID')!=null?cimTableUtils.getCellValue(record, 'GetEidDetails.SUB_EID'):cimTableUtils.getCellValue(record, 'GetEidDetailsByAccountNo.SUB_EID'))}"
                    update=":#{p:component('eidFlatDetails_pnlGrp')}"
                    process="@this :#{p:component('eid_pnlGrp')}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
        </f:facet>
    </cust:panel>

    <h:panelGroup id="eidFlatDetails_pnlGrp">
        <cust:panel export="true" id="eid_flat_details"
            rendered="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.eidFlatDetailsTbl ne null }"
            table="#{eidStatusInquiryBean.eidFlatDetailsTbl}"
            autoPublish="false" layout="table">
        </cust:panel>
    </h:panelGroup>


</h:panelGroup>
```

Can you please tell me why one works and the other does not

Tools: Primefaces 5.0

Comment: There is no datatable in the code above!

Comment: Do you know what a primefaces custom component is ?

Comment: So this is what stackoverflow has become now ? Instead of answering the actual question, you'll just change the question itself so that you get the points. *clap* *clap*
There are no two solutions that work. Only only solution works and I wanna know the reason.

Comment: The only real difference I see between the working and non-working appears to be that you've added `@this` to your process attribute. Since you were re-rendering the parent of both tables, wrapping your second table in it's own panelGroup shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: If you see the updated code, you can see that the parent of both tables is not "re-rendered" anymore.